# Stop post request on event

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a tooltip with data loaded from ajax:

```
$('.show_tooltip').hover(
    function(){
        $.post('getdata.php', function(data)    {
            $('#tooltip').html(data);
            $('#tooltip').show()
        });
    },
    function(){
        $('#tooltip').hide(); 
    }
);
```

It works.
But the problem is - when I hover it over element and quickly move mouse out, so `$('#tooltip').show()` have no effect, and it `hide()`. But then when data is loaded it popsup and stays shown without any hover.

What can be done about that. Is there any way to stop post request altogether?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jQuery AJAX methods return a [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object which is an extension of the native [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest) object, which has an `abort` method to stop the request:

```
var xhr;
$('.show_tooltip').hover(
    function(){
        //Save reference to the jqXHR object
        xhr = $.post('getdata.php', function(data) {
            $('#tooltip').html(data);
            $('#tooltip').show()
        });
    },
    function(){
        xhr.abort(); //Abort the request
        $('#tooltip').hide(); 
    }
);
```

Comment: I tried it, but after xhr is aborted and new post request is finished, all aborted requests are being executed one after another. So, `abort` just temporally stops request, it is still saved somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take `.show()` of the AJAX success function.

```
$('.show_tooltip').hover(
    function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'getdata.php',
            asynch
            data: data,
            success: function(){
                $('#tooltip').html(data);
            }
            $('#tooltip').show()
        });
    },
    function(){
        $('#tooltip').hide(); 
    }
);
```

Comment: If you do that then the tooltip is going to show with no content (since the content is set in the AJAX `success` handler). I don't think that's what the OP wants.

Comment: @JamesAllardice, you are right. But as far as I understand his question, his problem that is that the tooltip appears after mouseleave. Thats probably because the `hover()` triggered the AJAX request but the tooltip is shown on `success()` of the AJAX call, which is asynchronous by default.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem, but the question asked for a way to cancel the asynchronous request so that the tooltip doesn't display at all if the mouse has already left the element. See my answer.

Comment: @JamesAllardice, your answer is much better :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$('.show_tooltip').hover(
    function(){
        $.post('getdata.php', function(data)    {
            $('#tooltip').html(data);
            $('#tooltip').show()
        });
    }
);
$('#tooltip').bind("mouseleave", function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This post once code `event.preventDefault();`
Example:

```
$("#formName").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // here using code stop post (return false;)
    $.post('processing.php', $("#formName").serialize(), function(result){ $('#LimitlessDiv').html(result); });
});
```